# How many CSS attributes are stripped by Gmail?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I'm trying to send email by using Symfony and I found that I can't use **position** and **background: url()** because Gmail stripped them. So I want to know how many CSS attributes which Gmail stripped?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Gmail basically removes `<head>` tag and all "linking", like you mentioned `background URL`. This is vunerability because you can pass any data by encoding image (base64 encoding).

I belive Google never published details on this, but we can only presume.

I would suggest you bullet-proof test your mail [here](https://putsmail.com/)